# Spring-form multiple forms with same model atribute name properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello I am trying to to use spring-form.tld + spring MVC but I can't figure out how to solve this problem. Let's say I have two classes:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public String getname() {...}
    public void setname(String name) {...}
}
public class City {
    private String name;
    public String getname() {...}
    public void setname(String name) {...}
}
```

In both of them is property with same name - "name".
Now I got a jsp with two forms:

```
...
    <form:form name="person" modelAttribute="person">
        <form:label path="name">Person</form:label>
        <form:input path="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form:form>
    <form:form name="city" modelAttribute="city" method="post">
        <form:label path="name">City</form:label>
        <form:input path="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form:form>
...
```

and controller which serves my requests:

```
...
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView handle(@ModelAttribute City city,
        @ModelAttribute Person person) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("test.jsp");
    mav.addObject("city", city);
    mav.addObject("person", person);
    return mav;
}
...
```

Problem is that if I post **person** form the attribute name is inserted into person object but also into city. This example is nonsense but it illustrates my problem. I would like to somehow "bind" the person form with person object.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why do you use a single controller method to handle two different forms? Shouldn't you have a handleUser and a handleCity methods?

Comment: Thank you multiple methods works! I am learning java so I am doing mistakes like this :)

Comment: For anyone else who has a similar problem, but requires two persistent forms, ensuring none of the variables have the same name fixed my issue. Although I'm sure there was probably a nicer solution with using only a single form.