# Spring form path with multiple model attributes with the same property name

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

The problem is that I have a spring form and 2 @ModelAttribute params with the same properties in my controller. The 'commandName' parameter of the the form is set to one of my modelAttributes names. I was surprised that the  maps the property not only to the model attribute specified with 'commandName', but also to the second one.

I haven't found the exact solution here, except the similar to mine: [Spring-form multiple forms with same model atribute name properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552929/spring-form-multiple-forms-with-same-model-atribute-name-properties)

But in my case I can't see any 'strange things', I have one form, one Model attribute to bind this form, and one model attribute to have accsess to controller scoped @SessionAttribute.
I've also tried to use form's 'modelAttribute' parameter (Actually I can't see any difference between them), but it didn't help.

My code example:

view.jsp:

```
<form:form name="form" action="/myAction" method="POST" commandName="model1">
    <form:input path="property"/>
    ....
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Controller.java

```
@SessionAttributes("model2")
class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/myAction", method = POST)
    public String submitEditSite(final @ModelAttribute(value = "model1") Model1 model1,
                                 final @ModelAttribute(value = "model2") Model2 model2) {
        ....
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}
```

Model1.java    Model2.java

```
class Model1 {
    private String property;
}
class Model2 {
    private String property;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to prevent the setting of any property on `model2`, right?
Then this should do:

```
  @InitBinder("model2")
  public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("*");
  }
```